# What are good strategies for updating a live database table?

Tags: database, dev-to-production

I have a db table that gets entirely re-populated with fresh data periodically. This data needs to be then pushed into a corresponding live db table, overwriting the previous live data.

As the table size increases, the time required to push the data into the live table also increases, and the app would look like its missing data.

One solution is to push the new data into a live_temp table and then run an SQL RENAME command on this table to rename it as the live table. The rename usually runs in sub-second time. Is this the "right" way to solve this problem?

Are there other strategies or tools to tackle this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like messing with schema objects in this way - it can confuse query optimizers and I have no idea what will happen to any transactions that are going on while you execute the rename.

I much prefer to add a version column to the table, and have a separate table to hold the current version.

That way, the client code becomes

```
select * 
from myTable t, 
     myTable_currentVersion tcv
where t.versionID = tcv.CurrentVersion
```

This also keeps history around - which may or not be useful; if it's not delete old records after setting the CurrentVersion column.

Comment: thanks! I suppose I could also populate a new table <new_live_table_v2> that appends the new version to its tablename. Then the client could do a look up on the current_version table and query the most recent table accordingly. This would avoid adding an entirely new column to an already sizable table.

Comment: Also, turns out that the MySQL Rename command is atomic. For example, RENAME TABLE table1 TO table_bak, table_temp TO table1 is performed in one step and guarantees that table1 will always be accessible to the client. I think this is what I will do for now! That said, Rename will not persist foreign keys, so it is possible to mess with the schema when using InnoDB and foreign keys (we're using MyISAM). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Create a duplicate table - exact copy.

Create a new table that does nothing more than keep track of the "up to date" table.
MostCurrent (table)
id (column) - holds name of table holding the "up to date" data.

When repopulating, populate the older table and update MostCurrent.id to reflect this table.

Now, in your app where you bind the data to the page, bind the newest table.

Comment: thanks! Tough to choose between your answer and @Neville's below

Comment: Suppose this still won't get around the issue of keeping the data current since updates/inserts could be done while the swap is taking place?

Answer (score 0):

Would it be appropriate to only push changes to the live db table?  For most applications I have worked with changes have been minimal.  You should be able to apply all the changes in a single transaction.  Committing the transaction will make them visible with no outage on the table.

If the data does change entirely, then you could configure the database so that you can replace all the data in a single transaction.